# Problemas con postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

como estan? tengo un problema con un `select` en postgres. Cree una db con un user nuevo pero en `pg admin` al aplicar una query dentro del programa me retorna

```
ERROR:  permission denied for table users
```

Aplique una query para dar privilegios con:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO someuser;
```

como tambien una query para dar privilegios a la tabla pero nada :/

Comment: cuál es el query que quieres ejecutar?

Comment: select * from users por ejemplo.

Comment: ¿La db esta creada en el esquema public? Podría ser eso.

Comment: Mmm creo que si

Comment: Cuál es la DB nueva? CUál es el usuario nuevo? EN qué DB está creada la tabla users que buscas? Cómo te conectas para correr el select? Edita la pregunta y añade toda esta información para tratar de entender tu situación

Answer (score 0):

Puedes echar un ojo aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483555/postgresql-give-all-permissions-to-a-user-on-a-postgresql-database

En caso de que siga sin funcionarte, puedes hacerlo directamente desde PgAdmin: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/grant_wizard.html

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

podes probar con esto en principio

Esto da permiso a todas las tablas dentro del esquema public

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO someuser;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO someuser;
```

y esto solo para la tabla users

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON users TO someuser;
```